# Why is it revoked SSL certificate?

Tags: php, ssl

BadSSL indicates that this Url https://revoked.badssl.com/ has SSL revoked certificate.

In PHP, the expiry date from the SSL Certificate is set to `2019-09-11 12:00:00`

```
$url = "https://revoked.badssl.com/";

$orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
$read = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$orignal_parse.":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
$cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
$certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);
$validFrom = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $certinfo['validFrom_time_t']);
$validTo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $certinfo['validTo_time_t']);
$current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());


$validFrom = 2016-09-02 00:00:00 
$validTo   = 2019-09-11 12:00:00
$current   = 2017-02-20 19:00:00
```

`$validFrom > $current : False`

`$validTo < $current : False`

I thought that certificate is revoked if `$validFrom > $current OR $validTo < $current`. This not the case.

I can deduct that with PHP & cURL library, it's not possible to check certificate revocation. If the certificate was compromised and revoked by the owner, you will never know about it. Is it correct?

Comment: Certificates can be revoked outside of expiring, no?

Comment: Yes! as indicated by @pedrofb, Revoked != Expired.

Answer (score 1):

> Certificate is invalid/revoked if $validFrom > $current OR $validTo < $current

What you describe is neither *revoked* nor *invalid* but *expired*.
A certificate is invalid (among other things) if the signature does not match the certificate. It is revoked if the certificate authority explicitly revoked the certificate.

The revocation status cannot be seen by just looking at the certificate since revoking a certificate does not change it (impossible: it is already public). Instead one need to use the [Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) to query the status or download the [Certificate Revocation List (CRL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list) and check the certificate against this list.

Comment: I updated my post on the fact that with PHP & cURL library, it's not possible to check certificate revocation. If the certificate was compromised and revoked by the owner, you will never know about it.

Comment: @LeMoussel: looks like checks against CRL can be done although you need special libraries, see http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/compare.html#certrevoked. OCSP looks worse and support for OCSP is actually very bad in many languages like Python or Ruby too (Perl is better in this case). One of the reasons is that up to OpenSSL 1.1.0 there was no official API in OpenSSL for this.

Answer (score 0):

Revoked != Expired

A certificate is expired when `validTo < currentDate`. A certificate revoked by its issuing Certificate Authority means that this certificate must not be accepted in any electronic process.

While certificate validity period can be checked automatically, revoking a certificate is a manual action, for example because the data of the holder has changed or because the certificate has been stolen.

The Certificate Authority publishes a list of revoked certificates that can be checked online, using  CRLs or a OCSP request. Usually the certicate include the CRL/OCSP URL.

**Updated**

After reviewing PHP & cURL library seems there is no support. So I am afraid you can not solve your question easily

The library proposed by @StephenUlrich could be an option, but has the disadvantage that the CRL URL is not extracted from the certificate, so you would need to know what URL to use for each kind of certificate. Not also that some CAs only publish OCSP

Comment: If a certificate has expired, is it valid?

Comment: In general an expired certificate can not be be considered valid to be used in a electronic process:authentication, digital signature, etc. But a digital signature performed with a certificate that has expired is still valid if it has been protected with a time stamp. Apply this rule also to revoked certificates